# How do I get the pixel sprays for each character?

Tags: overwatch

While playing today, I got some cool "Pixel" sprays for beating certain character-specific achievements.

[image: Roadhog]
[image: It's high noon]
[image: Junkrat]
[image: Widowmaker]

I want them all!  What do I need to do to get each one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each character has two achievements. The "Cute" sprays are generally (but not universally) tied to skillful use of ultimate abilities, while the "Pixel" sprays are tied to more general use of the character. Specifically, the Pixel sprays are rewarded for:

**Ana:** Interrupt an enemy's ultimate ability using a Sleep Dart.

**Ashe:** Kill an enemy by shooting Ashe's dynamite from at least 30 meters away

**Bastion:** Get a total of 2 eliminations while in each of Recon mode, Sentry mode, and Tank mode in a single life *(the Tank kills do not have to be in the same use of the ultimate)*

**Brigitte:** Interrupt an enemy's ultimate ability with Brigitte's "Shield Bash"

**Doomfist:** Get a killing blow with Doomfist's Full Power Seismic Slam.

**D.Va:** Block 1500 damage with a single use of Defense Matrix

**Genji:** Kill 2 enemies with a single activation of Deflection

**Hanzo:** Get 3 killing blows with a single use of Storm Arrow.

**Hammond:** Absorb 1500 damage with Wrecking Ball's "Adaptive Shield" without dying

**Junkrat:** Use Concussion Mine to knock an enemy into your Steel Trap

**Lúcio:** Get 3 killing blows while wall-riding in a single life

**McCree:** Interrupt an enemy ultimate with Flashbang. *(Not all ultimates can be interrupted)*

**Mei:** Block 1200 damage with a single use of Ice Block

**Mercy:** Heal at least 200 damage on each of your five allies in a single life

**Moira:** Fully deplete both types of Moira's Biotic Orb without dying.

**Orissa:** Pull enemies into 1000 damage with a single use of Orissa's "Halt" ability

**Pharah:** Push someone to their death off a cliff using Concussive Blast

**Reaper:** Kill 3 enemies in a single clip *(that is, without reloading. You can use Death Blossom to soften them up, but the killing blows have to be with your primary fire)*

**Reinhardt:** Block 8000 damage with Barrier Field in a single life

**Roadhog:** Interrupt an enemy ultimate with Chain Hook

**Soldier 76:** Get 2 killing blows with a single use of Helix Rockets

**Sombra:** Hack 15 players in a single life.

**Symmetra:** Hit an enemy with 3 beams at once *(two of your sentries, plus your primary fire)*

**Torbjörn:** Absorb 500 armor damage with Torbjörn's Overload without dying.

**Tracer:** Recover a total of 400 health with Recall in a single life

**Widowmaker:** Get 4 kills with Venom Mines in a single match *(You can soften an enemy with your rifle after they have triggered it, as long as the damage-over-time from the Mine gets the killing blow)*

**Winston:** Destroy a total of 10 turrets (Torbjörn's or Symmetra's) and/or mines *(Widomaker's or Junkrat's)* using your Tesla Cannon in a single life

**Zarya:** Maintain 70% Energy or more for 60 seconds

**Zenyatta:** Get 4 assists or eliminations within 6 seconds using Orb of Discord

Comment: There has to be some formatting that makes this list less painful to read through. But I can't, for the life of me, figure out how :(

Comment: Nice answer! Can I be a pain in the butt and ask where you got this info from?

Comment: From the main menu, go to Career Profile, then the Achievements tab.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I was typing it from my phone at 1 AM.

Comment: Updated to clean up a few things, like clarifying that you don't have to get killing blows for Bastion

Comment: Good job with the formatting. Skimming through the text and finding the most relevant information is very easy now.

Comment: ITS 6 not 7 beams on symetra!!

Comment: I think for Reaper's pixel spray, as long as you tag at least 3 enemies with your primary fire first, you can still get the achievement if you kill them with your ult.

Comment: Since I've been bored with Overwatch for a good half a year it's no longer reasonable for me to keep updating this answer, and I've converted it to community wiki.

Comment: I believe Hammond's mines also count towards Winston's achievement.